# Makefile don't check dependency timestamps

Tags: makefile, target

I am writing a makefile like this

```
foo: bar
    touch foo
```

but I want `foo` to be built *only* if it's missing, regardless of whether `bar` is newer than `foo`. Is that possible with make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I want `foo` to be built only if it's missing, regardless of whether `bar` is newer than `foo`

In this case use an [order-only dependency](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
foo: | bar
    touch foo
```

Comment: That will make `bar` if it is out of date and will make `foo`is it does not exists. To just make `foo` is it does not exists:
`foo:\n\ttouch foo`

Comment: While "order-only" dependencies are a crucial feature of Make, in OP's case (as they've described it), the dependency on `bar` is wrong. OP wants `foo` to not depend on `bar`, so `bar` should not be in the list of dependencies for `foo`, as @shawnhcorey described.

Comment: @CameronTacklind _OP wants `foo` to not depend on `bar`_ - OP never said that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin "regardless of whether bar is newer than foo" == "foo does not depend on bar"

Answer (score 1):

To make a target if it does not exist:

```
foo:
    touch foo
```

To make `bar` if it's out of date and then make `foo` if it does not exist:

```
foo: | bar
    touch foo
```

Note that in the [example in the GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) that `$(OBJDIR)` does not depend on anything and only will be made if it does not exist.

**PS:** Some additional information on how order-only prerequisites work.

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ cat Makefile 
foo1: bar
    touch foo1

foo2: | bar
    touch foo2

foo3:
    touch foo3
$ make foo1 foo2 foo3
make: *** No rule to make target `bar', needed by `foo1'.  Stop.
$ touch bar
$ make foo1 foo2 foo3
touch foo1
touch foo2
touch foo3
$ make foo1 foo2 foo3
make: `foo1' is up to date.
make: `foo2' is up to date.
make: `foo3' is up to date.
$ touch bar
$ make foo1 foo2 foo3
touch foo1
make: `foo2' is up to date.
make: `foo3' is up to date.
$ make foo1 foo2 foo3
make: `foo1' is up to date.
make: `foo2' is up to date.
make: `foo3' is up to date.
```